# Prove that * is a binary operation

Tags: group-theory

I have the set $S=\mathbb{R}-\{-1\}$ and the operation $a*b=a+b+ab$ and I have to prove that $*$ defines a binary operation on $S$ my question is if is the same prove that is a binary operation and prove $S$ and $*$ is a group?

Comment: Proving that it's a group requires checking the group axioms. Implicitly, one of the group axioms is that the relation is indeed a binary relation.

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. It sounds to me like you are asking if "proving $*$ is a binary operation" is the same as "proving that $*$ is a binary operation and $(S, *)$ is a group"... which it clearly isn't.

Comment: @5xum If prove that $*$ is a binary operation is the same that prove that S with * is a group, but now I see is not correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, because it is necessary for $\ast$ to be an operation in order for $(S,\ast)$ to be a group in the first place. Sometimes this is explicitly stated, sometimes not, but either way it is a necessary condition.

Answer (score 2):

No, is not the same. The relation $*$ is a binary operation on $S$ if is a function from $S\times S$ to $S$, i.e., if for each $a,b\in S$, then $a*b$ is well-defined and belongs to $S$. It is clear that $a*b$ is well-defined in $\mathbb{R}$, so you have to check that if $a,b\neq -1$, then $a*b\neq -1$. This is easy, indeed $a*b=-1$ iff $a+b+ab+1=0$ iff $(a+1)(b+1)=0$ iff $a$ or $b$ is equal to $-1$.

So $*$ is really an operation on $S$, which means that $(S,*)$ is a magma (or grupoid). If you can also prove that $*$ is associative, has an identity element and that every element in $S$ is invertible, than you have that $(S,*)$ is a group.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know what I have to do but now I see